# How to bar plot from dataframe, where x axis are column names and legend are indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a `dataframe` as such:

```
Index                  A      C        D
Escheriecha coli       0.088  0.013   0.05
Human                  0.13   0.015   0.051
Candida                2.3    3.4     1.3
```

Now I want to make a `barplot` comparing those values. I want an x axis to be A, C, D and bar plots containing values in dataframe. I want bars to have different colours and legend, where we put values from indexes.

```
df.plot.bar()
```

Makes exactly opposite, meaning x axis are indexes and legend is column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transpose your dataframe to get the plot you want.

```
df.transpose().plot.bar()
```

[image: Bar plot showing columns A, C, and D and labels based on disease]